# Console: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, console.log

I am trying to fetch data from a MySQL database and display it (currently just logging it due to the error).

The error is :
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

My PHP code connecting to the database:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mywholeheart');

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `products`");

$result = mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

exit(json_encode($result));

?>
```

My JS code that has the fetch request:

```
fetch('server.php')
.then((res) => res.json())
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Almost every video or post on this topic has to do with spelling the place you're fetching the data from which is not what I am struggling with. They also suggest logging it as text but all that does is display my PHP code.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error and how I would go about fixing it?
I am not using any libraries or frameworks at this moment.

Comment: Replace `exit(json_encode($result));` with `print_r(json_encode($result));` and tell us what happens.

Comment: If you run `yourhost/server.php` alone in the browser, what is the result?

Comment: @masterguru the same error still appears

Comment: @SoroushBgm it downloads the server.php file for some odd reason?

Answer (score 2):

Your server doesn't execute `.php` files. It just get it as a text file.
what the error says about `<` character, it is actually the first character of your **text** file.
So that's the real problem here.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that but I'm not understanding how I could fix that.

Comment: @durellvicjardim: Check if your server has PHP installed and if not then install it